# Cannot access the server using XAMPP and PHP

Tags: php, xampp, macos-sierra

I'm brand new today to using PHP but I can't get anything showing on the page. I've installed XAMPP, started the server, mounted the volume and created a new file, index.php, which I've moved into a new folder called scripts inside htdocs. Based on the articles I've been following this should give me output at localhost/scripts/index.php but it is only giving me the 'requested URL not found on this server' response (I'm just running a basic echo 'hello world' line). Thanks for any help.

Going to just http://localhost shows the 'It works!' message but nothing else.

[image]

Comment: can you please share the error message screenshot with us?

Comment: Try `http://localhost/` first, then click on links

Comment: first off, does the "scripts" folder exist and is there in fact a file called "index.php" in that folder?

Comment: thanks pbu, i've edited the op to mention that

Comment: @poppashingles if you're trying to address someone in particular, you need as I did for you here and use the `@username` convention. They might no longer be present in the post.

Comment: @funk-forty-niner It definitely exists, I double checked my spelling to be sure but either it isn't looking in the htdocs folder or i've set up something in the server incorrectly, and thanks for the tip!

Comment: @poppashingles what is the OS that you're running this under and the version?

Comment: @funky-forty-niner I'm on Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: well, this could be anything. There are many results from using "requested URL not found on this server XAMPP sierra macos" as keywords. Go through those and see if you can use something from those results. Some can be found here on Stack and on other sites. I never dealt or worked with that OS, so I won't be of any further help, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are any processes running on port 80, if you have skype or torrent client please close them and try restarting xampp.

Also check if it running on your IP Address. open command prompt and type `ipconfig` for windows and `ifconfig` for mac.
once you get your ip address type it in the browser and see if you can find the server running.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I've not got anything running there at the moment as far as I can tell

Comment: Also check if it running on your IP Address. open command prompt and type ipconfig for windows and ifconfig for mac. once you get your ip address type it in the browser and see if you can find the server running.

Comment: I'm running on 127.0.0.1, putting that in manually gives me the same result as localhost

Comment: did you try 127.0.0.1:8080 or localhost:8080 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to save the file with correct extension i.e. .php just typing .php at the end sometimes doesn't work.

Try to do this,
1. Add double inverted commas **""**
2. File Save as Type - **All Files**
3. add **.php** at the end of your filename
[image: Check Red Quotation Marks]

Comment: I've tried re-saving the file in the style you suggested but it doesn't seem to have caused any difference. I think the problem must be on the actual server as I'm not getting the right response under localhost in the first place

Comment: post a screenshot if you can of the localhost. And also check if you have started apache and mysql in XAMPP Control Panel

Comment: At the moment the localhost is literally an h1 tag with 'It works!' in there, which feels like a lie at the moment to be honest :P It's green lights all around on the XAMPP control panel. Apache and MySql seem to be running alright